# C++ istream readsome(), rdbuf()->in_avail() doesn't work in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, istream

I want to read a file but only the part that has been read into the buffer. In other words I don't want to cause a disk "hit" if possible. For example if I have `ifstream("filename")` I would assume that it buffers the first n characters and that I should be able to read those characters using readsome(). That function doesn't work though because in_avail() always returns 0, and the C++ standard says that when in_avail() returns 0 then readsome() is to return 0.

Is anyone in Visual Studio (or windows in general), and are you able to use readsome() successfully on a file or standard input, or any type of stream? I am in Visual Studio 2010 and I can't read files using readsome(). Or am I using it wrong? This gives me output of all zeroes:

```
ifstream file("file.txt");
assert(file.is_open());
char buffer[255];
cout << file.readsome(buffer,1) << endl;
cout << file.rdbuf()->in_avail() << endl;
cout << file.gcount() << endl;
cout << endl;
```

Do you have any suggestion on how I can read only the buffered portion of the stream? Is there a portable way to get the buffer size and then read only that using read()?

Comment: The error is on line 14.

Comment: I don't know what you're talking about!

Comment: I'm talking about your code.

Comment: You should post code.  From your question it sounds like you might be trying to access the `streambuf` just after you open the file, before you perform any read operation.  At that point, the runtime will not have read anything into the `streambuf`, so it returns `in_avail() == 0`.

Comment: Ok that's a good idea. I posted some code.

Comment: So did the rest of my comment make sense?  There's nothing in the `streambuf` for `readsome()` to return because there's been no operation that fills the `streambuf` (opening the file doesn't perform the I/O to fill the buffer).

Comment: Opening the file does not fill the buffers, actual read operation does. Try reading 1 character first, then do `readsome`.